# Yii2 saving to db

Tags: database, yii2, save, registration

Yii does not save to db in $register. My aim is to make saving into db and logging a user if he is not there yet or just log in in if he is there.

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm'])){
        $users = User::find()->where("username = '".$_POST['LoginForm']['username']."'")->count();
        if ($users == '0'){
            $register = new User();
            $register->username = 'lak';
            $register->save();
        }
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }

    }

    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you have some fails i validation rules
if this the try using

```
 if ($users == '0'){
        $register = new User();
        $register->username = 'lak';
        $register->save(false);
    }
```

if with $register->save(false);  the values is saved  then check better for your validation rules ..